# Mongodb timestamp not displayed correctly in hive

Tags: mongodb, hadoop, hive

I am using mongo-hadoop connector to access mongo data in hive. My mongodb data is -

```
{ _id: 1,
   type:"simple",
  createddate:  { "$date" : "2015-03-24T05:04:26.963Z"}
}
```

I created hive schema -

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE demo
(
id STRING,
type STRING,
createddate TIMESTAMP         
)
STORED BY 'com.mongodb.hadoop.hive.MongoStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES('mongo.columns.mapping'='{"id":"_id", "type":"type", "createddate": "createddate"}')
TBLPROPERTIES('mongo.uri'='mongodb://{hostname}:27017/test.demo');
```

Schema gets created correctly and I can access mongo data in hive. But the value of timestamp is not returned correctly from hive.
In above case it returns the value of createddate as **2015-03-24 10:34:26.963** instead of **2015-03-24 05:04:26.963**

Can somebody please explain why this happens? How can I access the correct mongo timestamp in hive?
Hive version - 0.14.0
Mongo - 2.6

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a timezone problem. Dates in MongoDB are stored in a timezone-agnostic epoch format, but the conversion from gregorian to epoch and then back from epoch to gregorian seem to happen according to different timezones in your case. Are all servers using the same timezone?

Comment: @Philipp In above case both mongodb and hive are running on my machine (same timezone). Is there any way to stop hive from doing the time conversion?